# WKWebview not loading local HTML/CSS file

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am using WKWebview to load local html file. the folder resides in **tmp** directory. The relative path of js and css are in nested folders.**(../css/font.css,../js/player.js)**, where as html in parent folder. The Url not loading in the wkwebview

```
Root folder name - HTMLFiles
Root HTML Path -  HTMLFiles/HTML/index.html
CSS path - HTMLFiles/design/CSS/font.css
JS path - HTMLFiles/JSPath/JS/player.js
```

```
> > Below I am trying to read from temp directory and loading into
>     > wkwebview urlToLoad =  [NSString
>     > stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/HTMLFiles/HTML/index.html",
>     > NSTemporaryDirectory()];; SEL sel =
>     > NSSelectorFromString(@"loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:"); if
>     > ([self.webView respondsToSelector:sel] &&
>     > self.useLoadFileURLreadAccessURL) {    NSString* directory =
>     > [self.urlToLoad stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
>     >         ((id (*)(id, SEL, id, id))objc_msgSend)(self.webView, sel, [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlToLoad], [NSURL
>     > URLWithString:directory]);
>     >         [_webView loadFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlToLoad] allowingReadAccessToURL:[NSURL
> URLWithString:directory]];
>     >     } else {
>     >         // load the passed in URL
>     >         [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlToLoad]]];   }
```

Comment: What if, when you print out the urlToLoad String?

Comment: Could you clarify your problem in the body of your question, by editing it?

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView load only html from local storage. You can use [local server](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/CocoaHTTPServer/Listings/CocoaHTTPServer_m.html) for load files.